# How can I install LetsEncrypt certificates on a Bluehost dedicated IP address through cPanel?

Tags: cpanel, security-certificate

Looking for guidance to install a free Let's Encrypt SSL cert on shared hosting places like BlueHost or JustHost. (Not interested in procedure on other hosting places.)

I have a dedicated IP address. This is not for WordPress (which BlueHost/JustHost provides for free).

Prefer a solution that uses CPanel functions. Don't have command line access. BlueHost/JustHost does not have a "Let's Encrypt" choice in CPanel.

Comment: Did you do a web search?  Top result for me was https://www.garthmortensen.com/letsencrypt-on-bluehost-shared/

Comment: Yes. That result and many others from the googles, is old and outdated; applies to WP sites, and also requires command line access. I need procedure for non-WP domain.

Comment: If Bluehost don't provide letsencrypt for general hosting then you can't use LE certificates.  Personally, I reckon you should find another host...this is further proof that cheaper isn't better.

Answer (score 2):

***Unfortunately*, the most effective way to achieve your goal will be to use the command line.**

Since you have a "dedicated IP address," you should be able to gain access to the command line fairly easily using the instructions found here:

[Bluehost Web Hosting Help - SSH Access](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/180)

You will need to enable Sudo Access:

[Bluehost Web Hosting Help - VPS or Dedicated Hosting - Enabling Sudo Access](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2358)

According to [Bluehost](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/2240):

> The Bluehost system is setup with CentOS and is currently not compatible with any other OS configuration.

Therefore, you will need to use `yum` to install Let's Encrypt on CentOS. Here's a beginner guide to using `yum` on Bluehost:

[Bluehost Web Hosting Help - VPS or Dedicated Hosting - Using yum](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/2389)

And here is a very helpful guide for how to install Let's Encrypt on CentOS:

[How to Secure Apache with Let's Encrypt on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7)

---

If this task is too difficult, then I would recommend either transferring to a host that allows more flexibility, such as [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), or simply purchasing a commercial SSL Certificate:

[Bluehost Web Hosting Help - Purchasing or Renewing SSL certificates](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/ssl)

Comment: I use Dreamhost and they handle the Let's Encrypt SSL certs automatically.